# How to install Mono in Debian

Tags: linux, mono, debian

I am quite new to Debian and Mono. When I tried to install Mono in Debian (which is GNOME Version 3.14.1, Kali GUN/Linux2.0(sana) 32-bit) following the steps from:
http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage
and type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got:

```
# sudo apt-get update
Hit http://download.mono-project.com wheezy InRelease
Get:1 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy-apache24-compat InRelease [7,940 B]
Get:2 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy/main i386 Packages [56.5 kB]
Get:3 http://download.mono-project.com wheezy-apache24-compat/main i386 Packages [588 B]
Fetched 65.0 kB in 0s (266 kB/s)  
W: Failed to fetch http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x86/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

W: Failed to fetch http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian/dists/wheezy-apache24-compat/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-x86/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can i fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
This problem has been solved but another occurred. Here's the link to that problem:
[Packages have unmet dependencies when installing mono-devel in Kali (Debian)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427496/packages-have-unmet-dependencies-when-installing-mono-devel-in-kali-debian)

Answer (score -1):

I just googled a lot and played around. I typed the following in the terminal:

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
```

and it said: `x86`

As `x86` is not a valid Debian (derivative) architecture so I removed it by:

```
dpkg --remove-architecture x86
```

Then the `apt-get update` works!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11901210)

Comment: Did not really get what you mean. I am the author and I answered my own question later. Did you mean that I should not post it as an answer but comment it instead? @Tyler Jandreau

Comment: Yao that was a comment from a review of "low quality posts". I did not notice you had answered your own question. Disregard my first comment.