# Packages have unmet dependencies when installing mono-devel in Kali (Debian)

Tags: linux, mono, dependencies, debian

I tried to install mono-devel and typed `sudo apt-get mono-devel` in the terminal. But failed and got the following results:

```
~# apt-get install mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mono-devel : Depends: libgamin0 but it is not installable
          Depends: libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.22.0) but it is not installable
          Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.2.3.4-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: mono-csharp-shell but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried `apt-get -f install` but still not work. Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: try to compile mono from source, if the packages aren't installable on your distro that will be the only way to get it running.

Comment: did you mix some packages from external apt sources?

Answer (score 4):

You might have downloaded the wrong PPA in your Linux distribution.

```
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian stable-buster main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
```

The PPA repository mentioned in the Installation process on [mono-project](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian) website is for UBUNTU (Debian 10) not for other distributions (might be) as mentioned [here](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives).

Solution:

1. Delete `mono-official-stable.list` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder.
2. Run `sudo apt update`.
3. Finally, run `sudo apt install mono-devel`.

Comment: Life saver! If you want to do some coding, you should probably download the `mono-complete` package as well.